# How do I screen capture and interpolate the pixels to "nearestneighbor"?

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a tool that captures a portion of the screen that is around the mouse and displays that capture into a picturebox on the main form. The mouse cursor is surrounded with a second form (Form4) which follows the cursor and keeps it centered over the said form. Directly underneath the cursor on Form4 is a picturebox with it's backcolor set to Lime, as Lime is the transparency key for Form4. This is to make the picturebox see though. The area in this picturebox of the screen behind it is what is captured. 
As this is happening, I have the live screen capture being shown in another picturebox on the main form (Form1). That picturebox also has a "pixel grid" which is rendered on it using a Paint event. Everything works fine. But the problem is when I try to interpolate the pixels to "nearestneighbor" The top left of the picturebox on Form1 show up fine, but as it goes down and right, the pixels start to stretch a little bit and overlap the pixel grid. I even made an image to hover my mouse over to test this. The image is a checkered pattern of only 2 colors, each checker being only 1x1 pixel. Here is my code and here are some screenshots of what happens. Thanks!

```
        Dim pic As New Bitmap(Form4.PictureBox2.Width, Form4.PictureBox2.Height)

        Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Form4.Location.X + Form4.PictureBox2.Location.X, Form4.Location.Y + Form4.PictureBox2.Location.Y), New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)

        Dim bmpnew As New Bitmap(pic, 258, 258)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpnew)
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
            g.DrawImage(pic, 0, 0, bmpnew.Width, bmpnew.Height)
        End Using

        PictureBox2.BackgroundImage = bmpnew
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days, I finally figured out what was wrong.
The picturebox on the main form was a certain size, as was the picturebox on Form4. Basically, I was taking a screencap of the area within the picturebox on Form4 and resizing it to a bigger scale then putting that bitmap into the picturebox on the main form, and interpolation of course, blah blah blah.. What I have just figured out was that the pixels were stretching upon resize, it wasn't a perfect upscale for both the width and height so the pixels were actually being stretched. The picturebox on Form4 where the screencap took place, it was 42x42 but the picturebox on the main form was 258x258. It has to be divisible. In other words, the screencap size has to be multiplied by a number, say 4. The picturebox on the mainform should equal to that.
Below is the fixed code.

```
        Dim pic As New Bitmap(Form4.PictureBox2.Width, Form4.PictureBox2.Height)

        Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)
        gfx.CopyFromScreen(New Point(Form4.Location.X + Form4.PictureBox2.Location.X, Form4.Location.Y + Form4.PictureBox2.Location.Y), New Point(0, 0), pic.Size)

        Dim bmpnew As New Bitmap(pic, 252, 252)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmpnew)
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor
            g.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.Half
            g.DrawImage(pic, 0, 0, 252, 252) <<the correct size
        End Using

        PictureBox2.BackgroundImage = bmpnew
```

I even changed the size of the picturebox on the main form to 252x252. It works now. Thanks anyway. I hope this helps someone.
Below, is a picture of what it looks like now. This is what I was trying to accomplish.

[image]

[image: As you can see, now the pixels are lining up with the grid as intended. No more going beyond the bounds.]

Comment: Well done. Remember to enclose your objects in using blocks in the production code: `Dim pic As New Bitmap ...`, `Dim gfx As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(pic)` etc., because you're leaking a lot GDI resources right now.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by leaking? This is something I did not know. Could you please elaborate? Also, is this something I should do when it comes to using bitmaps and images in every way, such as opening an image with an openfiledialog or saving a bitmap to an image file or is this something I should only worry about when using bitmaps?

Comment: Any time you use some GDI+ resources. Bitmaps. Brushes, Pens, the Graphics object and so on. If you created those objects, you need to dispose of them. Either explicitly (`.Dispose()` method) or implicitly (`Using` statement). Those objects use vital (because scarse) resources. The importance of it also depends on how many objects you create. When instantiated in a `Paint()` event, it's really necessary. Just enclose your objects in a using block (as you have done with `Using g As Graphics ...`. (...)

Comment: Bitmaps can be cloned before dispoing the original object. In you code, you could write: `Using bmpnew As New Bitmap(pic, 252, 252) (...) PictureBox2.BackgroundImage = CType(bmpnew.Clone(), Bitmap)  End Using`  (a Clone or a New Bitmap because otherwise you would be assigning a disposed (invalid) object). The same for the other GDI+ objects. You can find information on this all over StackOverflow (and in many other places).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the advice. I guess I have some sanitizing to do.

Comment: Well, it's always like that. Cleaning the code, checking the resources/memory usage. Same old story. You have already  done a good job there, I think.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate that. Now, if I was not clearing the memory, would that memory still be used after closing the program or does it automatically clear when it is closed?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Windows can reclaim unused memory and the .Net [Garbage Collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/) is quite aggressive. This doesn't mean that the memory would be in good condition when those resources finally become available to the system. When memory is used without care, Windows might be forced to swap memory to disc, slowing down the whole system (causing lags for constant disc accesses). Of course this depends on how much memory a program allocates for its objects. It is good practice to take care of these "details".

Comment: Hey quick question. Do you know if it is possible to detect a mouseclick event on a mouse that is hooked? Currently, I have the mouseclick disabled across the entire computer while a timer is running. but when the timer is stopped, the mouse gets reenabled again. But I need the mouse click to stop the timer.
I am trying to allow the user to use the color grabber to grab any color on the screen but I don't want it to click or select anything while doing so. It seems to be a catch 22 situation.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly a "quick question". It also depends on the tools used to set the Mouse hook. If you used `SetWindowsHookEx()`, you can handle its `HookProc` callback to filter the mouse button pressed (wParam) and the mouse click coordinates (marshalling the lParam → MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) and then decide what to do if the time is not elapsed while returning `CallNextHookEx()`. But you should ask a new question about this, since is not related to contex of the current question.